# Is a single carbon atom stable?

Tags: atoms, stability

It is well known that single atom of oxygen is not stable, and it forms $\ce{O2}$ molecule. But elements like carbon form a network of repeated bonds. As answered in another [question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/carbon-atoms-at-the-edge-of-a-diamond), last atoms in such network are unstable and need to create some bonds.

Is it possible to have a (free-standing) single atom of carbon? Stable in the form of a stable powder like graphite or diamond.

If not, what is the minimum size of a carbon particle (diamond or graphite network)?

*Further Clarification:* I meant normal chemical stability to have a powder material at room temperature. I do not mean highly reactive carbon, quickly turning into a compound.

Comment: You seem to have several questions here.  I've answered your question title, but you also ask 1) about carbon specifically and 2) about how much carbon it takes to make a stable molecule.

Comment: Ultimately, stability has to be determined with respect to something. Helium gas is stable with respect to chemical reactions, but unstable with respect to nuclear fusion (even at 0 K, thanks to quantum tunneling; tremendous pressure and temperature just speed it up). But then *all matter* as we know it in the Universe is unstable with respect to subatomic particles. All atoms are expected to suffer [proton decay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton_decay) (and consequently neutron decay too) over sufficiently long timescales (at least around $~10^{35}\ yr$, but not more than $~10^{200}\ yr$).

Comment: @NicolauSakerNeto, yes, but it is Chemistry site, so you can safely assume that "stable" means "chemically stable".

Comment: There are a couple interesting platonic hydrocarbons which are related to buckyballs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_hydrocarbon

Answer (score 9):

> Is it possible to have a (free-standing) single atom of carbon?

It's definitely possible, but such an atom would be highly unstable and likely would have a short lifetime. An example of this happening is if you blasted some carbon material with a laser. Here's a really cool paper where researchers blasted carbon nanotubes and graphene with lasers and observed single-atom chains (not an individual atom in this case, but the same principle applies) of carbon exhibiting some very interesting electronic properties:

http://www.pa.msu.edu/cmp/csc/eprint/DT086.pdf

> If not, what is the minimum size of a carbon particle (diamond or
>   graphite network)?

Buckyballs (60 carbon atoms) come to mind.

**Tangentially related....**

A few years ago, a team of Australian scientists fabricated a single-atom transistor (the basic building block of integrated circuits). The atom was Phosphorus. Granted, the atom was not free-standing, but still very impressive. Such a device is extremely difficult to fabricate, and requires cryogenic temperatures, so it's doubtful that this would ever become a viable technology.

http://www.nature.com/nnano/journal/v7/n4/full/nnano.2012.21.html

Comment: The smallest member of the [Fullerene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fullerene) family is $\ce{C20}$. While the [Buckminsterfullerene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckminsterfullerene) is the most common of course.

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to have a (free-standing) single atom of carbon?

Yes, it is just the matter of having appropriate physical conditions. So, for instance, atomic carbon exist in the gas phase above 3,642 °C (according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_carbon)).

Comment: Well, the OP asked about room temperature, before he dies.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, initially there was no restriction on temperature.

Answer (score 4):

A single atom of helium is stable in nearly all circumstances.  Stability isn't a binary thing, though; whether an atom will react to form a molecule depends on what other atoms are available to react with (for instance, xenon is generally non-reactive, but will form molecules with fluorine), as well as temperature (as Wildcat mentions) and pressure.