# Carbon tetraradical

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, atoms, combustion, radicals

I was just reading through *Reactions: The private life of atoms* by Peter Atkins and I noticed that in Chapter 3, the chapter on the combustion reaction, the author writes:

> As we watch we see $\ce {CH_4}$ being whittled down to naked $\ce {C}$ as its $\ce{H}$ atoms are stripped away by radical attack.

"Naked $\ce {C}$" here seems to refer to a carbon atom, with four unpaired electrons. This seems rather surprising to me as I was thinking that such a reactive and unstable species could not possibly form. Thus, I would like to ask if a "naked $\ce {C}$" can possibly exist, though it may have a really short lifetime. Additionally, I would like to ask if this "naked $\ce {C}$" is considered a tetraradical or a biradical because in the ground state of carbon, there are only two unpaired electrons.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16477/is-a-single-carbon-atom-stable

Comment: Nice question.  Never saw such a species even in combustion mechanisms. Surely flame chemistry might be different . It is matter of T how many H and electrons are stripped.

Comment: Atomic carbon isn't unstable, but reactive. Book you're citing may simplify things for popular audience.

Comment: It exhibits very interesting reactivity. You can check it in "Reactive Intermediate Chemistry" textbook by Robert A. Moss, Matthew S. Platz, Maitland Jones, Jr.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In its ground state, naked carbon is triplet $^3P$, with two metastable singlet states $^1D$ and $^1S$ ($^1D$ being the one that participates in most reactions) while the tetraradical is the least stable one:
[image]

It can be synthesized by several different methods. Graphite vaporization by an electric arc or laser can be employed. Photolysis of suitable precursors can also produce atomic carbon:

[image]
[image]
Finely designed diazo compounds could be good precursors for atomic carbon, e.g. the diazo compound in the image below produces on heating a carbene, which immediately collapses to form benzene and atomic carbon. The problem with this approach is that the products can react further.

[image]

Another approach is to use diazotetrazole, but the drawback here is that diazonoium chloride obtained after the first step is extremely explosive.
[image]
I would also like to comment about the reactivity of atomic carbon since it is rather interesting. This reactive species is known to insert in C-H bonds and it can also abstract carbonyl oxygens to form carbenes:

[image]

If it is reacted with water, carbohydrates form:
[image]
[image]

When reacted with alkenes, cumulenes are usually obtained:
[image]
They insert into C-Br and C-Cl bonds, but abstract fluorine from compounds containing C-F bonds.

More about this rather interesting chemistry can be read in  "Reactive Intermediate Chemistry" by Robert A. Moss, Matthew S. Platz and Maitland Jones, Jr.

Comment: So would its reactivity be that of a biradical or tetradical? From the reactions it undergoes, it seems to be more of a biradical. But could u elaborate on this?

Comment: Sorry, I am also not very knowledgeable regarding the triplet and singlet states notation. Could you elaborate on those as well? If you could just explain those a bit more, I would be more than happy to award you the 50 points bounty. Thanks.

Comment: I have added a scheme to clarify the states for you. Assigning the notations should be a separate question, but here is a tutorial for you: https://youtu.be/Rerp-G5fdjg.

Answer (score 0):

The $^{5}S^{\circ}$ state, which lies just above the two singlet excited states referenced elsewhere here, could be considered a "tetraradical":

https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/ASD/energy1.pl

The quintet state seems to be of little importance, however.